# ASP.NET derived control, only render script on first page instance

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, viewstate

In my ASP.NET 4.0 web application, I have a class which is derived from a standard ASP.NET `<asp:TextBox>`.  This class needs to add client-side script, but the script only needs to be added to the page once even if there are multiple instances of the control on the page.

As I cannot access the ViewState of the page, what is best practise for making sure only the first control renders the script to the page.

I cannot use a static variable, as I obviously need it to be per-page... not per session/application.

This is roughly what I have at the moment...

```
Public Class MyTextBox
  Inherits TextBox

  Private Sub MyTextBox_PreRender(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    Dim script As String = "window.alert('Hello World');"
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "myscript", script, True)
  End Sub
End Class
```

Just to be clear - this is not a post-back issue, but only rendering the script on the first instance of the control within the page (whether in the page itself, or from a user control).

Comment: @Satpal, this is nothing to do with post-back, this is having multiple instances of the derived control on the same page, and making sure only the first control renders the script

Comment: Have you checked whether the script is really added multiple times if there are several instances of the control on the page? The documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx) states that based on the key and the type, duplicates are detected and the script should only be rendered once.

Comment: Thank you for making me look stupid @Markus... although to be honest, I did that myself ;-)  You are entirely right, and I didn't try it, I just assumed it would be rendered each time!!

Comment: it wasn't about making anybody look stupid :-) sometimes four eyes see more than two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.isstartupscriptregistered%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check if it's already registered:

```
Public Class MyTextBox
    Inherits TextBox

    Private Sub MyTextBox_PreRender(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
        If Not Page.ClientScript.IsStartupScriptRegistered("AlertHelloWorld") Then
            Dim alertHelloWorld = "window.alert('Hello World');"
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(MyTextBox), "AlertHelloWorld", alertHelloWorld, True)
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks Tim... @Markus (in his comment) pointed out that ASP.NET only renders one instance of the named client script anyway.  But your solution also removed the need to build the script each time, so that is definitely the way to go. Thanks again